# write an ascii extended code to xterm

Tags: zsh, xterm, ascii

I can copy and paste text with extended codes into xterm (really xfce4-terminal), and they show up just fine.  Piping extended characters to a hex editor shows them just fine for example: " Stéphane " in hex shows as: "53 74 c3 a9 70 68 61 6e 65 0a" -- the accented 'e' is hex: c3 and all's well.  But I can't figure out how to write an extended code within the xterm.  I've tried every variation on: " echo $'\xc3' " but nothing works.

Comment: The accented 'e' is not c3, but c3 a9 in your hex dump, as it should be on every modern system (i.e. UTF-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of two bytes 0xc3 0xa9 is the UTF-8 encoding of the pre-composed¹ `é`, `e` with acute accent U+00E9 character.

If your terminal emulator is configured to use that charset, because it was run in an environment where `locale charmap` returns `UTF-8` (like in a `fr_FR.UTF-8` locale) for instance, that's what you'll get.

In a terminal configured to use ISO8859-1 or ISO8859-15 charset (like in a `fr_FR.iso885915@euro` locale), you'll get the 0xe9 byte. In a `zh_HK.big5hkscs` locale, you'll get 0x88 0x6d and so on.

In `zsh`:

```
print '\ue9'
printf '\ue9\n'
echo '\ue9'
```

Will print the U+00E9 character encoded in the locale's charmap (the latter only if the `bsdecho` option is not enabled in which case you'd need to use `-e`; generally `echo` is an unportable command which is best avoided).

Instead of outputting characters based on their Unicode code points, you can also ask those builtins to print the bytes corresponding to the encoding of that character in this or that charset.

Either:

```
print -r -- 'é'
printf '%s\n' 'é'
echo -E - 'é'
```

Where we pass the bytes verbatim (as input from your terminal) to them and we disable the `\` expansions using the corresponding `-r`/`-E` options, or give them the byte values as octal or hexadecimal for them to expand. For instance, for the UTF-8 encoding of that `é` character:

```
print  '\xc3\xa9'   # hex
print  '\303\251'   # octal
printf '\xc3\xa9\n' # hex
printf '\303\251\n' # octal (POSIX)
echo   '\xc3\xa9'   # hex
echo   '\0303\0251' # note the extra 0s
printf '%b\n' '\0303\0251' # printf's %b recognises the same escapes
                           # as echo. Was introduced by POSIX to help
                           # people transition away from echo AFAIK.
```

Or you can use the `$'...'` form of quotes where the shell supports the same escape sequences (the normal ones, not the `echo` ones) and which are expanded before passing to the utility:

```
print -r -- $'\ue9' # expanded to eacute character in the locale's charmap
print -r -- $'\xc3\xa9' # passing the UTF-8 encoding of eacute
print -r -- $'\xe9' # passing the ISO8859-1 encoding of eacute
```

`$'...'` (initially from ksh93) will be included in the next version of the POSIX specification of the `sh` language, but not the `$'\uxxxx'` part (initially from zsh) as there's no consensus among the implementations that support it on which charmap is used to expand it and what to do if the corresponding character is not present in that charmap. For zsh, that's the charmap of the locale in effect at the moment the command is run, and it's a fatal error if the character is not present.

---

<sup>¹ not to be confused with the decomposed version `é`, made of two characters: `e` (U+0065) encoded as 0x65 in all charsets that are a superset of ASCII including UTF-8, followed by the *combining acute accent* character, U+0301, encoded as 0xcc 0x81 in UTF-8.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To get the `é` enter `echo -e "\xC3\xA9"`.

Assuming your xterm is set up for UTF-8 encoding then you can look up the UTF-8 hex encoding for the character you want to print at https://www.utf8-chartable.de/.

Comment: Thanks.  Now that I look more closely I see that the hex dump shows two characters: c3 and then a9.  So it's all UTF, I thought it might be extended ASCII but thereyago.